# I am trying to get a box to fade out when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript

When i click the fade button the box just disappears. I need some kind of time element, but I just can't seem to find the correct answer. I've tried a couple answers here on slack but I don't understand them and when I tried to apply them nothing worked. go to: doc

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){

document.getElementById("box").style.height = "300px";

});

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){

document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";

});

document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function (){  

document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 0.0;

});


document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function(){

document.getElementById("box").style.height = "150px";

document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "orange";

});

</script>
```

Comment: Are you looking for setTimeout?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
...
.fadeout {
   animation: 1s linear fadeaway;
}

@keyframes fadeaway {
   from {opacity:1}
   to {opacity:0}
}
</style>

<script>
...
document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", () => document.querySelector('#box').className += 'fadeout'));
</script>
```

quicker would be the following

```
$('#button3').on('click', () => $('#box').fadeOut(500);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for this.
Run the snippet below and see

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    $("#box").fadeOut();
  });
   $("#button2").click(function() {
    $("#box").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="box">

</div>

<button id="button1">Fade out</button>
<button id="button2">Fade in</button>
```